# Why table-driven LL (1) parser does not work with division and subtraction?

Tags: parsers

Everywhere, one grammar is used as an example table-driven LL(1) parser.

#### Grammar

```
S -> E | (epsilon)
E -> TE'
E' -> +TE' | (epsilon)
T -> FT'
T' -> *FT' | (epsilon)
F -> NUM | (E)
```

With this grammar you can only add and multiply. I wanted a little more so added subtraction and division operations.

#### my Grammar

```
S -> E | (epsilon)
E -> TE'
E' -> +TE' | -TE' | (epsilon)
T -> FT'
T' -> *FT' | /FT' | (epsilon)
F -> NUM | (E)
```

#### Parse table

```
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|     |   NUM   |    +    |    -    |    *    |    /    |    (    |    )    |    $    |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  S  | S->E    |         |         |         |         | S->E    |         | S->e    |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  E  | E->TE'  |         |         |         |         | E->TE'  |         |         |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  E' |         | E'->+TE'| E'->-TE'|         |         |         | E'->e   | E'->e   |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  T  | T->FT'  |         |         |         |         | T->FT'  |         |         |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  T' |         | T'->e   | T'->e   | T'->*FT'| T'->/FT'|         | T'->e   | T'->e   |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  F  | F->NUM  |         |         |         |         | F->(E)  |         |         |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

But I have a problem if used this grammar to build a parse tree the string 6*3/2, it turns out that the first operation is division and then the multiplication operation. I do not know why this is happening. Maybe this is because I have the wrong grammar or I'm doing something wrong. Help me.

Comment: Your parse table is wrong. Why does $E'$ row contain the rules for $T$ non-terminal, and $T$ row contains the rules for $F$?

Comment: @Vladislav Thank you for your remark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you naively generate a parse tree from

$$\begin{align}T\to& FT'\\
T'\to& *FT' \\
\mid&\; /FT' \\
\mid&\; \epsilon\\
\end{align}$$

then you're going to end up with something like this:

```
         T
        / \
       /   \
      /     \
     F       T'
     |      /|\
     6     / | \
          /  |  \
         *   F   T'
             |  /|\
             3 / | \
              /  |  \
             ÷   F   T'
                 |   |
                 2   ε
```

What you really want is this:

```
         T
        /|\
       / | \
      /  |  \
     T   ÷   F
    /|\      |
   / | \     2
  /  |  \       
 T   *   F  
 |       |
 F       3
 |
 2
```

But that belongs to a different, left-recursive grammar:

$$\begin{align}T\to& T * F\\
\mid&\; T / F\\
\mid&\; F
\end{align}$$

To use the second grammar, you'd need to use a different parsing technique (not the end of the world :-). To get the second parse tree, you need to do a little surgery while constructing it (or in a post-parse tree-walk, but that seems like overkill).

Because LL grammars cannot deal with left-recursive grammars, they cannot directly represent left-associative operators (which is most operators). Without left-recursion, you only have one way to represent a repetition, which means you have to use the same style to represent both left-associative and right-associative operators. That's not an issue in practice -- you certainly know the associativity of all operators in your language -- but you might find it annoying that you need to annotate the parser in order to get the right parse. If you use a bottom-up parsing technique, this annoyance vanishes.

Comment: That is, if I understand correctly, the table-driven LL (1) parser cannot correctly process the right-associative operator.

Comment: @none9632: What I'm saying is that the restrictions imposed by LL parsing make it impossible for the grammar to distinguish between left- and right-associative operators. In effect, both are represented as `operand (operator operand)*`, which is the normal way of writing recursive descent parsers. A parser can handle both associativities, but it must rely on information which is not embodied in the grammar. (Right-associative operators certainly exist. Aside from exponentiation, the most common one is assignment.)

Comment: Oops, I mean left-associative operator.

Comment: @none9632: Same answer.